# Problems with geolocation

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I want to make an application that shows your current position on a map with a marker. The code I've done seems to work but it doesn't display the marker. Can someone help me, please?
Here's my app.js:

```
    var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova']);

app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
});

app.controller('MapController', function($scope, $cordovaGeolocation, $ionicLoading, $ionicPlatform) {

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    $ionicLoading.show({
      template: '<ion-spinner icon="bubbles"></ion-spinner><br/>Acquiring location!'
    });

    var posOptions = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 20000,
      maximumAge: 0
    };

    $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then(function(position) {
      var lat = position.coords.latitude;
      var long = position.coords.longitude;

      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

      var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

      $scope.map = map;
      $ionicLoading.hide();

    }, function(err) {
      $ionicLoading.hide();
      console.log(err);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener($scope.map, 'idle', function() {

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: $scope.map,
        position: new google.map.LatLng(myLatlng)
        icon:'http://i.imgur.com/fDUI8bZ.png'

      });

      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "Here I am!"
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
      infowindow.open(map, marker);


    });
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using 
var long = position.coords.longitude;
whereas long is a keyword in javascript.  Check the link below.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp
Unless you are using ECMAScript 5/6 standard

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Latitude and Longitude in following way to `new google.map.LatLng(...)`

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: $scope.map,
        position: new google.map.LatLng(lat, long)
        icon:'http://i.imgur.com/fDUI8bZ.png'

      });
```

Hope this will help to you

Answer (score 0):

Spent a very hair-tearing hour or so trying to get the good old W3C geolocation example to work in my particular application. Didn't see this:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only

If you are NOT using https you may (will?) get a silent, non-functioning outcome, both in Chrome and Firefox! As soon as I switched to https, it was fine.